# Plot with a normal and a reversed y axis

Tags: r

I have data sets containing daily precipitation and discharge data. Now I would like to plot everything in one plot. All data sets are of length 61, so they can share the same x axis. The discharge data should be plotted the "normal" way, meaning that the y axis starts at the bottom and is placed on the left side. The precipitation data should be plotted "from the top", meaning that the y axis is reversed and placed on the right side.

Here is some code for a minimal reproducible example:

```
precipitation <- runif(61, min=0, max=25)
discharge <- runif(61, min=370, max=2610)
```

The result should approximately look like this:

[image]

Anybody with an idea how to achieve this?

EDIT: thanks pascal for the answer that implies the usage of *ggplot2*.

I also found a way by myself to do it with Base R, in case it could help anybody in the future:

```
precipitation <- runif(61, min=0, max=25)
discharge <- runif(61, min=370, max=2610)

# plot with Base R
par(mar = c(5, 5, 3, 5), xpd = TRUE)
plot(precipitation, type= "l", ylim= c(0,80), ylab= "Precipitation [mm/day]", main= "Comparison", 
     xlab= "Day", col= "blue") 
par(new = TRUE)
plot(discharge, type= "l", xaxt = "n", ylim= rev(c(0,5000)), yaxt = "n", ylab = "", xlab = "", col= "red", lty= 2)
axis(side = 4)
mtext("Discharge [m³/s]", side = 4, line = 3)
```

The *ggplot2* way looks a bit fancier of course.

Comment: Hi climdrag. Could you add a MRE?

Comment: Hi dario. I am sorry, but what do you mean with MRE?

Comment: [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610). But generally, it's really, really not a good idea to have two (non transformed) y axis. [Link to famous answer by H. Wickham](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099219/ggplot-with-2-y-axes-on-each-side-and-different-scales)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*ggplot2* can be used to make plots with a second, inverted axis. One has to specify `sec.axis` in `scale_y_continuous()`. I'm using a transformation ((100-x)*100) for your data and apply it to the axis as well, so that it fits. This can be changed to any numbers.

```
ggplot() +
geom_line(aes(y=precipitation, x=1:61), col="orange") + 
geom_line(aes(y=100-discharge/100, x=1:61), col="blue") +
scale_y_continuous(name="rain", sec.axis=sec_axis(~(100-.)*100, name= "discharge"))
```

[image]